# ¿Cómo hacer que al seleccionar una opción del spinner ejecute una acción?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un activity con 2 Spinner, uno depende de la selección del otro (esto lo hago cargando diferentes arrays desde string.xml, no se si sería la manera correcta), esta parte funciona bien, el problema es que quiero que según qué opción se seleccione en el 2º spinner (digamos el secundario), me haga una acción, en este caso escribir un texto en un TextView.

Este sería el código que tengo hasta ahora (no seáis duros, que como digo mis conocimientos no son gran cosa):

```
    public class Main11Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnItemSelectedListener{


    public Spinner spinnerZona, spinnerPosicion;
    public TextView Comentarios;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main11);

        spinnerZona = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerZona);
        spinnerPosicion = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPosicion);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.ZonasEP0,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerZona.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinnerZona.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        int[] Posiciones = {R.array.SinPosicion, R.array.PosicionesEP0_K, R.array.PosicionesEP0_E, R.array.PosicionesEP0_F, R.array.PosicionesEP0_G, R.array.PosicionesEP0_GR};


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            Posiciones[position],
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinnerPosicion.setAdapter(adapter);


    }



    @Override

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


      }}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la siguiente línea:

```
tuSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int itemSeleccionado, long l) {
                    if (itemSeleccionado==opcion) {
                       //Puedes hacer algo si se cumple la condición....
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
```

Cuando escoges algo en la variable `itemSeleccionado` del `onItemSelected` va a pasar la posición que se seleccionó en el `Spinner`, es ahí cuando puedes usar un `if` o un `switch` para hacer determinada acción.

Comment: Esto creo que ya lo había probado, tanto con "if" como con "switch", pero no me funciona con el segundo spinner, sólo con el principal. Si meto otro "setOnItemSelectedListener" me da errores, como si únicamente se pudiese usar uno en todo el código.

Comment: Tendrás el código para ver cómo lo hiciste?

Comment: Estoy mirando que haces un implements, no lo has intentado sin usar el implements y asignar a cada Spinner el 'new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()' es posible que cuando hagas por separado el evento, pueda funcionar

Comment: Voy a probar eso que me dices, dame un momento y comento. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Creo que se dónde puedo tener el problema, voy a hacer unos cambios y luego comento.

Comment: Bueno... como se suele decir "para mear y no echar gota" a raíz de tu pregunta de porqué usaba el "implements", me vino la inspiración. Con tanto borra, prueba, etc, en una de estas se quedó una llave "}" fuera de donde tenía que estar, no daba error porque el "void" sí que estaba cerrado. A mayores se ve que también borré la línea que unía la variable String al TextView del activity. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, se agradece siempre, pero más aún cuando uno no tiene los conocimientos necesarios.

Comment: De nada mi estimado, estamos para servir.

Answer (score 0):

aquí te envío un código para tal fin. Detallalo y ajustalo a tus requerimientos. En este caso se rellena una variable con la acción de interés pero puedes usarlo para ejecutar otras operaciones.

```
private void setupSpinner() {
    // Crear adaptador para el spinner. La lista de opciones son del String array 
    // El spinner usara este layout por defecto
    ArrayAdapter genderSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array_gender_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Especificando dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item por linea
    genderSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    // Aplicando el adaptador al spinner
    mGenderSpinner.setAdapter(genderSpinnerAdapter);

    // Estableciendo el valor entero de mSelected a una variable cada vez que se seleccione un item
    mGenderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_male))) {
                    mGender = PetsContract.PetsEntry.MASCULINO; // Male
                } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_female))) {
                    mGender = PetsContract.PetsEntry.FEMENINO; // Female
                } else {
                    mGender = PetsContract.PetsEntry.SIN_GENERO; // Unknown
                }
            }
        }

        // Debido a que el AdapterView es una abstract class, onNothingSelected debe ser tambien definido
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mGender = PetsContract.PetsEntry.SIN_GENERO; // Unknown
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar y comento.

Comment: Revisando el código que has puesto, veo que ya lo hice también, pero únicamente me funciona con el primer spinner si hago eso, con el segundo (el dependiente del primero) no hace nada. Tengo la duda de si es porque no pongo el código en donde debiera, pues no se hasta que punto y como puedo crear dos "setOnItemSelectedListener" sin que se pisen. Si pongo "spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); " en el onCreate y añado otro "spinener2.setOnSelectedListener(this);" debajo, es como si se pisaran y no aparecen luego las opciones del segundo.

Comment: Tengo una duda de tu pregunta, define mejor para que usarias 2 spinner y porque son necesarios en tu programa. Que quieres lograr con esto y segurmante se te pueda orientar mejor.

Comment: Solucionado, gracias la respuesta (ayuda) del compañero @CodeFluid y la tuya propiaencontré el problema, una llave "}" cerrando un void antes de tiempo. Muchas gracias como digo por vuestro tiempo. Se agradece.